# Why does my C++ code display Arabic text?

Tags: c++, wstring

I have a code piece that uses `std::wstring` and `wstringstream`:

```
static std::wstring floatToWString(float val)
{
    std::wstringstream stream;
    stream.precision(8);
    stream.setf(std::ios_base::fixed, std::ios_base::floatfield);
    stream << val;
    return std::wstring(stream.str());
}
```

When I observed inside of 'stream' variable of my code, I saw something like that:

[image: screenshot of debug]

As I understand these are some Arabic phrases. How is this possible?

I work in Visual Studio 2013 in Debug and X64 configuration.
Is it about something wstring or Visual studio debug mode or something else?
I suspected about it is just a memory piece left but after I reseted my computer it is same.

EDIT : for some who says it is about random memory block or it is about not null terminated string, I tried it in another sole program like that :
[image: Just try this]

Comment: you might want to edit your post to something less abnormal and more precise.

Comment: Probably the buffer inside the stream is not zero-terminated.

Comment: BTW, this is Arabic, not Muslim.

Comment: i said it is some arabic muslim phrase

Comment: Surely all that's relevant is that it's Arabic text. I've removed your mentions of Islam as they are irrelevant.

Comment: @Thomas Well it says "Bismillahi Rahman ir Raheem" which means "In the name of Allah, the most gracious and kind". So yup it is arabic and Muslim but I don't see why the OP has to say his code has converted to Islam when he is specifically talking about unicode characters.

Comment: Jon skeet I can read it, it is islamic like NSNoob said

Comment: What we mean is that the **content** *doesn't matter at all*. It could be Christan, Jewish, Buddhist or whatever... The question is why you get this output, isn't it?

Answer (score 5):

This would have been very much easier if you had posted text instead of a screenshot.

`936.37829590`

That's your `double`.

The rest is stuff that just *happens* to be in memory. The stream is not zero-terminated, so the debugger cannot tell where to stop displaying memory contents.

Why is that phrase there? We can hardly tell. It's not something the code you posted does.

Perhaps some other part of your program defines a string literal of that content. Perhaps it's the contents of some file you've read before you called this function.

Comment: I restarted my program,restarted my computer and used same code piece in another program,nothing changes, same characters come

Comment: @AkınYılmaz: Well, can't help you there. Coincidence of some kind. Does it matter?

Comment: @AkınYılmaz: "Not deserved"? *Something* in your computer -- something *indeterminate*, something *other* than the code you posted -- happens to put that phrase into memory near to the stack of your function. Could be the OS, the compiler, a library, a previously-read file, or even malware on your system. *There is no way for us to know*. It gets displayed by the debugger because `std::stringstream` is not zero-terminated. That is what I said, and that is as much as *anybody* could say without inspecting your machine. You have some attitude there that needs to be checked...

Comment: Yup he deserves 5 up-votes at least. Thats why he has mine.

Answer (score 2):

I'm just guessing here, and that guess is what I wrote in my comment: The buffer is not zero-terminated. That means that the debugger will not know where the string actually end, and continue to read uninitialized memory until it finds the terminator, which may be a long way away.

What's in that uninitialized memory is, technically, *indeterminate*, but most likely just whatever contents happened to exist in the physical memory that was mapped to your process. So either earlier in your program, or in a previous program, there happened to be this phrase.